# JAVASCRIPT Count occurrences of lower case letters in a string

Tags: javascript, string, char

I have a javascript problem that I am very confused about

> Write a function stringCase that takes a string with mixed uppercase and lowercase characters and return the string in either all uppercase or all lowercase depending on which letter case the string has more of. If the string has equal upper and lower case characters, convert the string to all lowercase. Do not include any loops, length property, or native methods (exception: toLowerCase() & toUpperCase() allowed).

I can immediately think of a few approaches to this problem, like using a loop to check each character, or using a replace method and regex and getting the length of the result. However, the prompt prohibits me from using loops, length property, and native methods.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick here is to use recursion to do the loop. You can manually track the pointer and counts.

```js
const stringCase = (s) => {
  let i = 0;
  let count = 0;

  const process = () => {
    const curr = s[i++];
    if (!curr) {
      return count <= 0 ? s.toLowerCase() : s.toUpperCase();
    }

    if (curr.toLowerCase() === curr) {
      count--
    } else {
      count++
    }

    return process();
  }
  
  return process();
};

console.log(stringCase('Aa') === 'aa');
console.log(stringCase('AaA') === 'AAA');
console.log(stringCase('aa') === 'aa');
console.log(stringCase('AA') === 'AA');
```

Answer (score 1):

So my answer is similar to JBallin's, except that I used a frequency counter to keep track of the upper and lower case counts.  This reduces the amount of moving parts for the helper function.

```
function convertString(str) {
    // object to keep track frequency of upper/lower case letters
    const frequencyCounter = {
        upper: 0,
        lower: 0
    }

    let currentIndex = 0

    // helper function to increment frequencies of letters
    function checkCase() {
        const currentChar = str[currentIndex]

        // if current index is outside length of string and returns undefined
        // break recursive loop by returning
        if (!currentChar) return

        if (currentChar.toUpperCase() === currentChar) {
            frequencyCounter.upper +=1;
        } else {
            frequencyCounter.lower +=1;
        }

        // increment current index and recursively call helper function
        currentIndex++
        return checkCase()
    }

    // start helper function
    checkCase()

    // check for which case to convert the string to and return that string
    if (frequencyCounter.upper > frequencyCounter.lower) {
        return str.toUpperCase();
    } else {
        return str.toLowerCase();
    }
}
```